# Can't run Xilium. CefGlue built on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, chromium-embedded

'Hi all, I downloaded `Xilium.CefGlue` and built the source on Visual Studio (xilium-xilium.cefglue-b22787699e57), I also downloaded `cef_binary_3.1453.1236_windows_xilium` and copied the `libcef.dll` to the Xilium Winforms demo as the apps requires it to run but when I run it I get the following error:

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B
```

I've targeted x86, can I get some help?
Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're just wanting to check things out, try Debug build. I got same as you in Release, but Debug ran ok.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here's the steps I used to get the samples working in VS 2012:

1. Get the code from [Xilium.CefGlue on github](https://github.com/red-gate/Xilium.CefGlue). (The one I used was [c3d674a3a8](https://github.com/red-gate/Xilium.CefGlue/tree/c3d674a3a8fa7ca05de1d058a3b52250e7e65096))
2. Open the *Xilium.CefGlue* solution in VS2012
3. Remove or don't build the *CefGlue.Demo.GtkSharp* project (it didn't interest me & I didn't have the needed libraries)
4. In the Configuration Manager, select Active Solution Platform to be `x86`
5. Ensure that the target framework settings cooperate between projects. (e.g. *CefGlue.Demo* & *CefGlue.Demo.WinForms* by default are v2.0, but they depend on *CefGlue* which is v4.5) (For simplicity I set them all to v4.0 Client profile and it worked.)
6. Build solution — should succeed
7. Copy Xilium files from the unzipped [cef_binary_3.1453.1236_windows_xilium](http://xilium.dmitriid.com/download/cef/3.1453.1236/cef_binary_3.1453.1236_windows_xilium.7z) to the output folder (`bin\x86\Debug` or `bin\x86\Release`). Minimum requirement seems to be:

   - `libcef.dll` and `icudt.dll` from `.\Debug` or `.\Release`
   - `cef.pak` and the `locales\` folder from `.out\Debug` or `.\Resources`
8. Set *CefGlue.Client* as the StartUp Project
9. Run it

Comment: (Note that if you get the code from [Xilium.CefGlue on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/src), that code doesn't have the same problem with the .NET framework version on the CefGlue project being too new; that problem was [introduced into the Github copy](https://github.com/red-gate/Xilium.CefGlue/commit/ea43848e6f736d73daa30bfb6f4f6ebd575ba296). On the surface, it looks like the Bitbucket code is being more actively developed than the Github code—at the time of making this comment)

Comment: Doesn't matter where I get the code or Debug vs Release.  I followed your steps and it launches.  But crashes almost immediately.  No real information except from the Event Viewer: `Faulting application name: Xilium.CefGlue.Samples.WpfOsr.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5319043f
Faulting module name: libcef.DLL, version: 3.1650.1617.0, time stamp: 0x52fa7305
Exception code: 0xc0000005`