# CEFGlue version API Hash

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I have tried to run the example in c# (http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/) but it says: "CEF Version Hash API is not the same". Although I have downloaded the CEF version(CEF 3.1650.1503) reported here: http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/ And included it as a reference...

Is there a complete VS solution available with all correct dependencies included?

Answer (score 1):

That cefglue page seems to be outdated. Go to sources: https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/src/ > Click Tip > Tags. Binaries for given tag (v3.branch.revision) can be downloaded from http://www.cefbuilds.com/ .

Comment: I have checked out v3.1916.1857 from bitbucket.org/xilium, and downloaded the corresponding cefbuild. Then followed the steps over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124852/cant-run-xilium-cefglue-built-on-visual-studio-2012, but I still cannot run the example in visual studio, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SvenCornelis what error happens?

1. Be sure that you are use same architecture. Best choice for now is x86. Don't forget to choose correct configuration in VS.

2. Put CEF binaries in correct place - i.e. CefGlue.Demo.WinForms/bin/x86/Debug . Copy binary files from Release & Resource folders (i.e. one folder with libcef.dll and second with icudtl.dat).

If it is still wrong - include error details in yours question.

Comment: @SvenCornelis - It works - Use https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/src/8004e433e8ce5259017d085a1b12b174ffb40bd5/?at=v3.2171.1875.1 with build "v3.2171.1875.12014-10-17 CEF 3.2171.1875 - Chromium 39.0.2171.19" from http://cefbuilds.com

Comment: @czarek: I'm a first time bitbucket user. What do you mean by Tip > Tags? Are you basically talking about checking out based on that tag? Kind of lost by what seems to be talk about revision tags (?) and hash tags, lol...